# Calculate day/ month/ year difference between dates on separate rows grouping by ID

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a df that contains dates per event on separate rows for several individuals like so (I have 2 rows per ID):

| ID | date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-04-26 |
| 1 | 2021-03-11 |
| 2 | 2022-01-24 |
| 2 | 2018-09-12 |

I am looking to calculate the length of time between the dates for each ID - so my output should look like this:

| ID | yrsbetweendates |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 4 |

I think something with `dplyr` and `mutate` might be the solution but I am not sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably there is some more "simple" and "concise" way to do it but here is one way. It uses functions from `dplyr` and `lubridate` as well as some base R functions.

```
library(lubridate)

df <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,2,2),
             date = as.Date(c("2022-04-26", "2021-03-11", "2022-01-24", "2018-09-12")))

df <- df %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(ID) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(yrsbetweendates = ceiling(lubridate::time_length(abs(diff(date)), "years")))
```

Answer (score 0):

I used time_length and difftime function for calculating years.

But ID:2 years span became 3 years.

```
library(lubridate)
as.integer(
    time_length(
        difftime(strptime("2022-04-26", "%Y-%m-%d"), strptime("2021-03-11", "%Y-%m-%d"))
    , "years")
)
# 1

as.integer(
    time_length(
        difftime(strptime("2022-01-24", "%Y-%m-%d"), strptime("2018-09-12", "%Y-%m-%d"))
    , "years")
)
# 3
```

Is this result correct for you?